# How to display a long text in column?

Tags: android, textview, multiple-columns

I have a long text and I would like to display it in columns, like in a newspaper.
Is there a way to do this, customing the text.layout?
or I really need to cut the text by myself in a constructed textview?

[EDIT]
I do know how to display textview side-by-side (linearlayout and so on), I am actually starting with a big String that I want to display in columns. I gave up the idea of webview and css (for known performant issues). I then want to know if there is another way than cutting my text, with the following code:

```
int height    = textView.getHeight();
int scrollY   = textView.getScrollY();
Layout staticLayout = textView.getLayout();

int lastVisibleLineNumber  = staticLayout.getLineForVertical(scrollY+height);
int start = staticLayout.getLineEnd(lastVisibleLineNumber);
int end = staticLayout.getLineEnd(textView.getLineCount()-1);
String textToDisplayIntOtherView = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);
```

Could I simply display my text in columns, customizing the Text.layout ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:width="100dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="first column" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_txt"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:width="100dip"
    android:textColor="#0481ab"
    android:text="second column"/>
```

If can customize the width of each textview in multi line with the desided width 
        android:width="100dip"

Comment: that does not answer me, I want columns, not a maximum of lines in a textview.